# Display Date only jquery datetime picker for mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

How do i default to date only in the jquery date time picker.  The first time the page loads the text box defaults to both date and time but after i choose a date it only shows the date portion. The date is bound to a model.

View code

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.EndDate)

@*java script*@

 $(function () {
$("#EndDate").datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

So what i want is the datetime textbox to always show date only without time.

Comment: Check [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You better create a custom function to convert DateTime object to date and use this in he view.

Server side:

```
 public static string ShowDate(this DateTime dateTime)
        {          
            string dateFormat = String.Empty;
            dateFormat ="yy/mm/dd";// or the format you need

            return dateTime.ToString(dateFormat);
        }
```

In the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new {  @Value =Model.EndDate.DisplayDate() })
```